# Curl to add an index pattern and a json file to create dashboard

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I would like to use a curl command to add an index pattern to my kibana index. I am using logstash to index my data and indexes looks like that: `logstash-{the current date}`

I am using this command:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/.kibana1/_mappings/_doc/
{
 "properties": {
         "index-pattern":{
                 "properties":{
                         "title": "logstash*",
                         "timeFieldName": "time"
                 }
           }
 }
}"
```

I am getting this error: `curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 67`

I have also a json file and I would like to send it to kibana by using curl.

**Another try:**

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/.kibana1/_mappings/_doc/" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
 "properties": {
         "index-pattern":{
                 "properties":{
                         "title": "logstash*",
                         "timeFieldName": "time"}}}}'
```

**Error:**

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Expected map for property [fields] on field [title] but got a class java.lang.String"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Expected map for property [fields] on field [title] but got a class java.lang.String"},"status":400}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `"` after your last brace ?

Comment: because after the XPOST there is a  "

Comment: But a `"` is missing after your url : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/_executing_searches.html

Comment: @rbcvl I edited my post

Comment: Can you show me your index pattern please ?

Comment: logstash-lemaout173050-2018.11.14, an example the name of the user and date could be different

Comment: What do you have in Kibana Dev Tools when you try a `GET <your_index>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved:**

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:5601/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/logstash" -H 'kbn-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
 {
"attributes": {
 "title": "logstash-*","timeFieldName": "time"
 }
}'
```

More info here:
[REST API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.5/api.html)

and here: [elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/curl-to-add-an-index-pattern-and-a-json-file-to-create-dashboard/156818)

Comment: I tried above & got error as below

`{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized"}`

This is because I am trying it on authenticated kibana instance. How can I login kibana & try this API

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, If you have a secured instance of kibana

```
curl -XPOST -u USERNAME:PASSWORD http://localhost:5601/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/index-pattern -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "kbn-xsrf: true" -d '{"attributes": {"title": "index-pattern-*"}}'
```

There should be at least one index which matches our index pattern & there should be at least one entry under index.

Comment: Thanks, that can help others. But even if there are no indices in kibana, it must work.